# Why are both github workflows running when they are configured to only run on their respective branches?

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflows, `develop.yml` and `production.yml`.

develop is configured to run on `develop`:

```yaml
name: Develop
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
      - develop
jobs:
  perform-linting:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "14.x"
      - name: Install base dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Bootstrap
        run: lerna bootstrap
      - name: Run ESLint
        run: lerna run lint
```

And production is configured to run on `master`:

```yaml
name: Production
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Deploy to Heroku
        uses: akhileshns/heroku-deploy@v3.12.12
        with:
          heroku_api_key: ${{secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY}}
          heroku_app_name: ${{secrets.HEROKU_APP_NAME}}
          heroku_email: ${{secrets.HEROKU_EMAIL}}
```

However, pushing changes to `develop` or `master` will trigger both of these workflows to run:

[image]

In the above scenario, why is production being run when I only pushed to develop?

Comment: Because you're listing branches for the wrong thing: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags. Workflow dispatch is _manually_ triggered: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your configuration effectively says 'run on all pushes, only allow manual dispatch on a particular branch' (though the latter isn't an option it seems).

You probably mean:

develop.yml

```
name: Develop
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  workflow_dispatch:
```

production.yml

```
name: Production
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:
```